# How can I make a for loop increment a variable based on the value of a string character?

Tags: javascript

I feel like it's something super obvious, but I can't figure out what's going on here. When I console.log(countA) it returns 2. I know I'm gonna kick myself once I see what's wrong with it.

```js
let n = 10
let s = 'aba'
let x = n / s.length
let countA = 0  
let newStr = s.repeat(x)

for (i = 0; i < newStr.length; i++) {
    if (s.charAt(i) == 'a') {
        countA++
    }
}
```

When I `console.log(newStr)` I get abaabaaba

I've tried changing the loop to:

```
for (i = 0; i < newStr.length; i++) {
    console.log(newStr.charAt(i))
}
```

Which displays all 9 letters. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `console.log(arr)` — what is `arr`?

Comment: Anyway your `for` loop iterates (with the undeclared variable `i`) from 0 up to the length of `newStr`, but the `if` statement is checking the original string `s`, not `newStr`. There are two `a` characters in `s`.

Comment: `s.charAt(i) == 'a'` should be `newStr.charAt(i) == 'a'`

Comment: Also the "changed" `for` loop looks exactly the same as the original.

Comment: Woops, I edited it. Also yeah, I knew it was gonna be something dumb. Thanks dude.

Comment: What results do you expect?